# Computing limit under Lebesgue

Tags: real-analysis

Compute

> $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_1^\infty \frac{1+ (-1)^n \exp (-nx^2)}{x^2} dx\ .$$

When I expand this expression, the first terms is just integral $1/x^2$ and I think the second term will tend to zero as $n\to \infty$?

Thanks in advance for assistance.

Comment: Hi, I changed the format of your question such that it is more readable. Please check if the integrand is correct. I am not sure about that.

Comment: Thanks for that,I am still trying to figure out how to use the mathematical symbols so anything I post is readable.

Comment: With respect to your formula, the first term is 1/x^2 only Thanks again

Comment: Also just noticed that exp should be exp(-n*x^2) and not exp((-n^2)*x)

Comment: Do you mean $\frac{1 + (-1)^n \exp(-nx^2)}{x^2}$?

Comment: Apologies for delay in response...    yes this is the problem

Answer (score 2):

For odd $n$, the integral is zero. So you have to show that it goes to zero for even $n$. That is, you need to show that 
$$
2\int_1^\infty\,\frac{\exp(-n^2x)}{x^2}\,dx\to0.
$$
For this, you can use that $x\geq1$, so $\exp(-n^2x)\leq\exp(-n^2)$ and then
$$
\int_1^\infty\,\frac{\exp(-n^2x)}{x^2}\,dx\leq\exp(-n^2)\,\int_1^\infty\,\frac1{x^2}\,dx=\exp(-n^2).
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

> $$ e^{-n^2 x} \leq e^{-x} .$$

**Added** And note that $\frac{e^{-x}}{x^2}$ is an integrable function on the interval $[1,\infty)$. So, the LDCT can be applied.

Comment: @Downvoter: Why do you rush to down vote the answer? What's the down vote for? This downvote is misleading.